# Not able to use .env file with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use the `.env` file to set some variables on my `docker-compose.yml` like it's described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file):  and I'm not able to make it work. I tried exactly the same example from the doc and I keep getting the same error:

```
WARNING: The TAG variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

This is the part of my `docker-compose.yml` where I use the variable:

```
version: '2.0'
services:
    mariadb-service:
        container_name: database-container
        image: mariadb:${TAG}
```

And this is my `.env` file:

```
TAG=10.1
```

I have docker-compose version 1.6.0.

Comment: what version of docker-compose do you use? version 1.7 (or 1.6 i dont remember) and less didn't supported .env file. 
use 1.8

Comment: It's version 2.0 @BukharovSergey. According to the doc, it should work or I missed something.

Comment: version of docker-compose is 2. type `docker-compose -v`

Comment: ah ok! I have docker-compose version 1.6.0. So should I upgrade all docker ? @BukharovSergey

Comment: Yes, upgrade, version 1.7 added support for .env. https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.7.0 (I'll let @BukharovSergey post the answer since he pointed you in the right direction)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

only docker compose 1.7+ has supported `.env` file. You need to update docker-compose

you can check you version `docker-compose -v`

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll try it.